# Jumping out of the bootloader to the next sector

Tags: assembly, osdev

I have a function "outside" which is placed on the 2nd sector of the hard drive and I want to access it after executing all the needed stuff in my bootloader. But after reading 2nd sector and jumping to that label, PC just goes somewhere and doesn't execute anything.

```
[org 0x7c00]
    mov bp, 0x8000 
    mov sp, bp
    mov bx, 0x9000 
    mov dh, 2 
    call disc_read
    jmp outside
    jmp $

%include "src/disc_read.s"
%include "src/print.s"
hello_World_str: db "Welcome", 0

; padding and magic number
times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55 

outside:
    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov al, 0x41
    int 0x10
    jmp $

times 512 - (outside - $) db 0
```

disc_read.s:

```
disc_read:
    pusha
    push dx
    mov ah, 0x02 ; function
    mov al, dh ; number of sectors to read, where dh is head number
    mov cl, 0x02 ;  sector, 0x01 - bootloader, 0x02 - next sector
    mov ch, 0x00 ; cylinder to read
    mov dh, 0x00 ; head number
    int 0x13 ; main function (interrupt)
    jc disc_error
    pop dx
    cmp al, dh
    jne sectors_error
    popa
    ret

disc_error:
    mov bx, disc_error_str
    call print
    call print_nl
    jmp $
sectors_error:
    mov bx, sectors_error_str
    call print
    call print_nl
    jmp $

sectors_error_str: dw "Incorrect number of sectors read", 0
disc_error_str: dw "Disc read error", 0
```

print.s:

```
print:
    pusha
    mov ah, 0x0e
    print_loop:
    mov al, [bx]
    inc bx
    cmp al, 0
    je print_end
    int 0x10
    jmp print_loop
    print_end:
    popa
    ret

print_nl:
    pusha
    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov al, 0x0a
    int 0x10
    mov al, 0x0d
    int 0x10
    popa
    ret
```

The expected result: `A` and it just goes into infinite loop.
The actual result: Infinite loop or wandering of PC

Comment: You seem to be loading to `0x9000` though ... and that even only if `es` happens to be zero since I don't see you setting it to anything.

Comment: so i should set `es` to `0x9000`?

Comment: First you should decide where you want to load ... since your code as is assumes consecutive loading that means you should load to `0x7e00`. So set `bx` to that and `es` to zero. In general, you should of course also be setting `ds` and `ss` and using `0x8000` for `sp` doesn't sound like a good idea (stack will grow down and collide with your code).

Comment: the thing i noticed is jumping to `0x9000` actually executes my code. but if i set `es` to `0x9000` or `0x900` it will add up to the address of label (may be something like `0xde2`, i dont know) and it will make some mess of an address

Comment: Yes, jumping to `0x9000` will execute your code since that's where you load it. Note at that location there will be a mismatch between the assembler's idea of addresses and the actual addresses.

Comment: @Jester, if i load code at `0x7c00`, it will overlap with my actual code or do something really bad and it won't work at all

Comment: @em3rald1 Jester suggested loading at **7E00h** not 7C00h.